# How to remove gaps around SVG symbol without using viewBox

Tags: svg, width, symbols, spaces, viewbox

I'm trying to use SVG symbols as described in this [CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/#article-header-id-1), but get a gap on the left and right around the SVG and it's width is `300px` wide.

I want the SVG to fill the full width of the container. Adding `width: 100%` to the SVG doesn't help.

[I've made a codepen](https://codepen.io/rubans89/pen/yrBXEO) to explain what is happening. The first example shows the problem.

Adding a viewBox attribute corrects the issue in the second example, but that's not ideal because I'm generating the SVG symbol from a folder of SVGs using webpack. So the viewBox information will have to be copy/pasted every time I reference an SVG in the HTML. This isn't ideal when you consider other people might want to edit the SVGs at a later date and might not realise they have to manually update the viewBox info in the HTML, which would result in broken looking icons.

This would become as unwieldy as having to explicitly add the dimensions of an image to all `<img>` tags. Not a great situation!

Is there any other way to fix it without adding a viewBox attribute?!

Comment: Give your svg a viewBox like you did in the 2-nd example.: `viewBox="0 0 90 90"`. If your SVG has a `viewBox` attribute and no width or height will fill the full width of the container. An svg without a `viewBox` will have a default size of 300/150 px.

Comment: Do you know why this is the case? I don't want to have to add any information about the viewBox in case I make changes to the SVG dimensions over time and forget to update it. It could get hard to maintain, especially since my SVG symbol reference is actually generated using webpack from a folder of SVGs.